# What are "unavoidable generic type problems" in Eclipse for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, types

Eclipse can be configured to "*ignore unavoidable generic type problems*" when setting the preferences for the Java Compiler in the "*Errors/Warnings*" panel.

What are such "unavoidable" generic type problems in Java? Is it safe to ignore these? When do they arise?

Comment: @DavidHarkness, Was it on this site? Otherwise, read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18956/what-should-i-do-if-the-answer-to-the-question-is-first-result-of-a-google-searc), especially if you're the one that downvoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm) of the feature:

> When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning even when it detects a generic type problem that could not have been avoided by the programmer. **As an example, a type may be forced to use raw types in its method signatures and return types because the methods it overrides from a super type are declared to use raw types in the first place.**

So, for example:

```
class Test {
    public void method(ArrayList list) {
    }
}

class TestSub extends Test {

    @Override
    public void method(ArrayList list) {
    //                 ^^^^^^^^^
    //     Complain on use of raw type or not?

        System.out.println("Overridden");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm):

> When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning even when it detects a generic type problem that could not have been avoided by the programmer. As an example, a type may be forced to use raw types in its method signatures and return types because the methods it overrides from a super type are declared to use raw types in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should never really ignore warnings. They're there for a reason. Try to fix whatever is causing them in general. Sometimes they're runtime-safe, but can improve code readability, sometimes they're really because of something that can make you code blow up.

A great deal just make your code more robust/readable/maintainable.  Plus, ignoring them might make your work harder in future, when you (or someone else) need to modifiy your code.