# How to avoid warnings when implementing an interface that uses raw types?

Tags: java, generics

I am implementing the [IProcessFactory](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/IProcessFactory.html) interface that has the following method:

```
IProcess newProcess(ILaunch launch, Process process,
                    String label, Map attributes);
```

As you can see it uses the raw Map type. When I implement this method with the same signature Eclipse gives the following warning:

> Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map should be parameterized.

Replacing `Map` with `Map<?, ?>` gives an error. So what is a proper way to implement such an interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is a proper way to implement

To the extent of my knowledge you are forced to use raw types in such situations. Indeed Eclipse refers to them as "unavoidable".

> How to avoid warnings when implementing an interface that uses raw types?

If you're using Eclipse you can disable these warnings under the *Errors/Warnings* section in the preferences.

See this answer for further details:

- [What are "unavoidable generic type problems" in Eclipse for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762717/what-are-unavoidable-generic-type-problems-in-eclipse-for-java)