# How to avoid generics warnings when using "raw types" as static field / return type?

Tags: java, generics, unchecked, raw-types

This is basically a follow on to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747339/is-there-a-generic-way-to-create-an-un-modifiable-list-set-map-from-collection-l) from yesterday. I tried to implement "the most generic way" (I could think of) in order to build "really" un-modifiable collections. The code below works fine; but it requires to suppress warnings ("rawtypes" and "unchecked").

I tried all kinds of things to avoid those warnings; but simply could not find an alternative. So, my question is: is there a clean way to avoid the warnings that I am suppressing?

( I saw this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772796/how-to-avoid-warnings-when-implementing-an-interface-that-uses-raw-types); but I am not 100% sure if it really applies to my code; as I am not sure if I could write down the "Generator" interface without using the raw type there).

```
private interface Generator<T> {
    T generateNewInstance();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private final static Generator ListGenerator = new Generator<List>() {
    @Override
    public List generateNewInstance() {
        return new ArrayList();
    }
};

public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableListBasedOnCloneOf(List<T> elements) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> newInstance = makeNewInstanceOf(elements.getClass(), ListGenerator);
    newInstance.addAll(elements);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(newInstance);
}

private static <T> T makeNewInstanceOf(Class<T> incomingClass, Generator<T> fallbackGenerator) {
    try {
        return (T) incomingClass.newInstance();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
        return fallbackGenerator.generateNewInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here: if the list is wrapped in an `unmodifiableList`, why does it matter what type the underlying list is? Why isn't `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(elements))` sufficient?

Comment: Just read my other question. The point is: it isn't. That Collections method only adds a **decorator** to an existing list. If you access that "initial list" through an un-decorated interface, you can change that list; and then your supposedly un-modifiable list changes under the cover.

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new ArrayList<>(elements))` isn't a view of `elements`: it copies `elements` into a new list (exactly like you do here), and the reference to that new list isn't accessible by anything other than the `unmodifiableCollection`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use an existing solution. For instance, Guava has some great immutable collections which are not only more performant than these decorator-based methods, but also do things like avoiding unnecessary copying. The main caveat of Guava's immutable collections is that they don't support null values.

Comment: As I have written in that other question that I am mentioning in this question: guava is not an option.

Comment: "For instance". I didn't say it had to be Guava.

Comment: Well, I asked for "other options" in that other question; and nobody did point out another implementation. And unfortunately we are pretty much restricted regarding usage of external 3rd party libraries ;-( ... but sorry: thanks for your attempts to help. It was a rough morning for me; and I shouldn't get defense when people are trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a copy of the `List<T>` into a new `ArrayList<T>`, and pass that reference inline to `Collections.unmodifiableList`, nothing other than the unmodifiable decorator has access to the copy to modify it:

```
    List<String> original = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"));

    // This simply decorates original, so updates to original are
    // reflected in this list.
    List<String> unmodifiableDecorator = Collections.unmodifiableList(original);

    // The reference to the new ArrayList is scoped to the call to
    // Collections.unmodifiableList, so nothing else can have a
    // reference to it.
    List<String> unmodifiableCopy =
        Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(original));

    System.out.println("Before clear:");
    System.out.println(original);
    System.out.println(unmodifiableDecorator);
    System.out.println(unmodifiableCopy);

    original.clear();

    System.out.println("After clear:");
    System.out.println(original);
    System.out.println(unmodifiableDecorator);
    System.out.println(unmodifiableCopy);
```

Output:

```
Before clear:
[Hello, World]
[Hello, World]
[Hello, World]
After clear:
[]
[]
[Hello, World]
```

So `unmodifiableCopy` isn't modified, and can't be modified unless you can somehow convince the `unmodifiableList` to give the delegate reference to you.

Since you can't modify it, you don't need to make the copy the same concrete list type as the input list. Just make it an `ArrayList`, since it has pretty much the best read performance that can be achieved with a `List` implementation.

So your method, without warnings or extra classes, can be:

```
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableListBasedOnCloneOf(List<T> elements) {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(elements));
}
```

Comment: The whole point of my implementation was: what if that "backing list" is not an ArrayList? But maybe a LinkedList? The point of my implementation is to only use "ArrayList" as fallback, when the code is unable to create a list of the same nature as the one that is coming in ...

Comment: What is the advantage of having a linked list backing it? The unmodifiable list can only use methods defined on `List`; the only methods for which `LinkedList` has an advantage are mid-list insertions or deletions, which aren't used. All the read-only methods perform the same or worse compared to ArrayList.

Comment: Well, the example is about list; but I have in mind to provide "truly un-modifiable" wrappers around all 5 methods from Collections. And its the same thing there. And to be really clear about that: I don't think an answer that contains basically the same code as the question isn't really an answer.  I knew that I can make a copy using ArrayList; but that is not what I asked for.

Comment: The answer is the  same in all (6) cases: use an implementation for each method which has the best read performance and preserves insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

It's not always possible to avoid a @SuppressWarnings annotation. I try to limit its scope to a local variable.

I came up with this:

```
private interface Generator<T> {

    T generateNewInstance();
}

private static class ListGenerator<T> implements Generator<List<T>> {
    @Override
    public List<T> generateNewInstance() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
};

public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableListBasedOnCloneOf(List<T> elements) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<List<T>> clazz = (Class<List<T>>)elements.getClass();
    List<T> newInstance = makeNewInstanceOf(clazz , new ListGenerator<T>());
    newInstance.addAll(elements);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(newInstance);
}

private static <T> T makeNewInstanceOf(Class<T> incomingClass, Generator<T> fallbackGenerator) {
    try {
        return (T) incomingClass.newInstance();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
        return fallbackGenerator.generateNewInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. That saves one of the warnings; at the subtle price of a single "new" statement (probably that was premature optimization; but I intentionally put down a solution that tries to minimize the "activities" that take place for the "good" case when no exception is thrown).

Comment: `incomingClass.newInstance()` can bypass compiler support for checked exceptions.  If you call `incomingClass.getConstructor().newInstance()` it will compel you to catch `InvocationTargetException` which will wrap exceptions thrown in the constructor, allowing you to handle them or use the `fallbackGenerator` as you see fit.