# Possible to add generics to implementation of a non-generic interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics, java-6

Is it possible to generify an implementation of the interface if the interface definition does not use generics? I do not have control over the interface I need to implement, but would like to suppress "unchecked" warnings for my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some issues can be resolved, some can not.

If the interface for instance looks like this:

```
interface OldInterface {
    List someMethod();
}
```

then sure, you can implement it by

```
class NewClass implements OldInterface {
    public List<String> someMethod() {          // DOES COMPILE.
        ...
    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, the interface looks something like

```
interface OldInterface {
    void someMethod(ArrayList list);
}
```

then there's nothing you can do about it programming wise.

```
class NewClass implements OldInterface {
    public void someMethod(ArrayList<String> list) { // DOES NOT COMPILE.
        ...
    }
}
```

This is what is referred to as an [unavoidable generic type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762717/what-are-unavoidable-generic-type-problems-in-eclipse-for-java). Luckily these warnings can be suppressed, at least in Eclipse, by checking *Ignore unavoidable generic type problems* under

*Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings*

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the return value is always possible when overriding, it is called *co-variant return types*. Adding a generics element is just that.

Otherwise, as already noted, restricting arguments is not allowed. When overriding, you may use a wider type for an argument, it is called *contra-variance*.